# Matlab pause function that returns the keystroke?

Tags: matlab, input, keyboard

I'd like to use a function in some matlab scripts that would do the following:

- Pause until user hits any single key
- Return the key stroke hit by the user

The `pause` function doesn't work, because it doesn't return the user keystroke.  The `input` function doesn't work, because it requires the "enter" key to be hit.  The `keyboard` command dumps you into the full command line window which I don't want (although might be useful for future work).  Note, there are ways to do this from figures, i.e. if a figure has focus, you can sniff keystrokes using the 'KeyPressFcn' handler.  But I want to do this from scripts.  Worst case, I can use the `input` command, but was hoping for something that required fewer keystrokes from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on MathWorks. Does it do what you want: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7465-getkey

Comment: I think this does the trick.  It uses a non-visble model figure and a KeyPRessFcn handler....  Very clever.